# Using my Python Web Crawler in my site

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x

I created a Web Crawler in Python 3.7 that pulls different info and stores them into 4 different arrays. I have now come across an issue that I am not sure how to fix. I want to use the data from those four arrays in my site and place them into a table made from JS and HTML/CSS. How do I go about accessing the info from my Python file in my JavaScript file? I tried searching in other places before creating an account, and came across some things that talk of using Json, but I am not too familiar with these and would appreciate some help if that is the way to do it. I will post my code below which I have stored in the same directory as my other sites files. Thanks in advance!

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    # lists to store data
    names = []
    gp = []
    collectionScore = []
    arenaRank = []

    url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/21284/gid-1-800-druidia/'
    response = get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # username of the guild members:
    for users in soup.findAll('strong'):
        if users.text.strip().encode("utf-8") != '':
            if users.text.strip().encode("utf-8") == '\xe9\x82\x93\xe6\xb5\xb7':
                names.append('Deniz')
            else:
                names.append(users.text.strip().encode("utf-8"))
        if users.text.strip().encode("utf-8") == 'Note':
            names.remove('Note')
        if users.text.strip().encode("utf-8") == 'GP':
            names.remove('GP')
        if users.text.strip().encode("utf-8") == 'CS':
            names.remove('CS')

    print(names)

    # GP of the guild members:
    for galacticPower in soup.find_all('td', class_='text-center'):
        gp.append(galacticPower.text.strip().encode("utf-8"))
    totLen = len(gp)

    i = 0
    finGP = []
    while i < totLen:
        finGP.append(gp[i])
        i += 4
    print(finGP)

    # CS of the guild members:
    j = 1
    while j < totLen:
        collectionScore.append(gp[j])
        j += 4
    print(collectionScore)

    # Arena rank of guild member:
    k = 2
    while k < totLen:
        arenaRank.append(gp[k])
        k += 4
    print(arenaRank)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

TLDR: I want to use the four lists - finGP, names, collectionScore, and arenaRank in a JavaScript or HTML file. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: First minimal question, do you know how to render your `collectionScore` data as text into a webpage that's generated by your python script? The rest of the full answer is kind of based on this.

Comment: No, I am only a college student and although I've coded many websites using HTML and CSS as well as some JS, this is the first in depth site I am doing. I code with C++ and Java in my classes so writing the Python was quite easy, its implementing it into my site that I do not understand at all @Geuis

Comment: Ok this is gonna be fun, frustrating (at times), and a great learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this will be somewhat long but I'm going to try breaking it down into simple steps. The goal of this answer is to:

1. Have you get a basic webpage being generated and served from python.
2. Insert the results of your script as javascript into the page.
3. Do some basic rendering with the data.

What this answer is not:

1. An in-depth javascript and python tutorial. We don't want to overload you with too many concepts at one time. You should eventually learn about databases and caching, but that's further down the road.

Ok, here's what I want you to do first. Read and implement [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972) up until the "Creating a Signup Page" section. That starts to get into dealing with Mysql, which isn't something you need to worry about right now.

Next, you need to execute your scraping script when a request for the server. When you get the results back, you output those into the html page template inside a script tag that looks like:

```
<script>
  const data = [];
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

Inside the brackets in `data = []` use `json.dumps` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to format your Python array data as json. Json is actually a subset of javascript, so you just output it as a raw javascript string here and it gets loaded into the webpage via the script tag.

The `console.log` statement in the script tag will show the data in the dev tools in your browser.

For now, lets pause here. Get all of this working first (probably a few hours to a day's work). Getting into doing html rendering with javascript is a different topic and again, I don't want to overload you with too much information right now.

Leave comments on this answer if you need extra help.

Comment: Im Just looking at this now, so I dont have questions yet, but I just want to say how much I appreciate your time and help! Thank you so much!

Comment: No prob. We all got started somewhen =)

Comment: Update.. I got it running by moving the if statement outside of the function but now when I run it on the localhost webpage it a 500 internal server error. Also realized I cannot return each item because returning ends the function, so Im a bit stuck. I will continue to work on it while waiting for a response and keep you updated.

Comment: Another update. I guess I have to return something. I tested and at the end of the main function simply wrote return "Welcome!" like in the tut and the error stopped and it printed welcome. When I try to return one of my lists though, nothing prints and the error comes back.

Comment: Can you share your code somewhere like on a git gist?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/U2EzKID95/981bc9ca197234a1397f86bb04340c1c
@Geuis here you go. Im sorry if Im being annoying. Im just really eager to figure this out. I really do appreciate this!

Comment: Having some trouble with my local python env. Will get back to you when I get it running

Comment: please, take your time. I’m further along than I ever would have gotten without you. Cannot thank you enough!